# Unexpected org-export text duplication of hyperlinks

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Given the following in my org-mode:

```
**** heading
***** [[https://somewhere.com][somewhere.com]]
***** [[https://somewhereelse.com][somewhereelse.com]]
```

(which my editor displays as links)

and the following options:

```
#+OPTIONS: ::t f:nil toc:nil tags:t num:nil author:nil H:11
```

org-export to text produces:

```
heading
=======
[somewhere.com] <https://somewhere.com>
* [somewhere.com]
  [somewhere.com] <https://somewhere.com>
* [somewhereelse.com]
  [somewhereelse.com] <https://somewhereelse.com>
```

There's duplication here which is unexpected and odd because it only happens to the link under the first point. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: LaTeX export and HTML export both work properly on this file, so it is very likely a bug in the text exporter only.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `org-ascii-links-to-notes` to `nil` - it is `t` by default. The doc string of the variable says:

> org-ascii-links-to-notes is a variable defined in ‘ox-ascii.el’.
>
> Its value is t
>
> Non-nil means convert links to notes before the next headline.
> When nil, the link will be exported in place.  If the line
> becomes long in this way, it will be wrapped.

I have to admit I don't really understand its purpose, but I rarely use `ascii` export and this setting is very much specific to that export engine.

You can use a file-local variable (`C-h i g(emacs)File variables`) to set it for this file only if you don't want to change it globally. Putting that in a  a separate section at the end of the file (it has to be at the end of the file BTW), and marking the section with the `noexport` tag, is a convenient way to keep this stuff in the file but never see it in the exported document. Something like this:

```org
#+OPTIONS: ::t f:nil toc:nil tags:t num:nil author:nil H:11

* heading
** [[https://somewhere.com][somewhere.com]]
** [[https://somewhereelse.com][somewhereelse.com]]


* Local variables                                       :noexport:

# Local Variables:
# org-ascii-links-to-notes: nil
# End:
```

Comment: Did you try this? DId it solve your problem?